# Use insert, inner join and ignore/skip over nulls

Tags: sql-server

I've very basic SQL experience and have been stuck with this SQL problem for a few days.
I've 2 tables. I need to move 3 columns of info from one table to the other.

Table A, the table I'm moving info into has 8 columns 3 of which is set to not accept null values.

how can I move over just the 3 columns and skip over or insert '0' into the column's that require values?

I'm using MS SQL server 2005 express.
This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO account (sSurname, sName, sIdNo)
SELECT Client.LASTNAME, Client.FIRSTNAME, Client.DATEOFBIRTH
FROM Client
INNER JOIN Account__MEMBER
ON Account__MEMBER.AccountKEY=Client.AccountKEY
ORDER BY Client.LASTNAME;
```

I've tried to research this but have not come across anything useful.

Comment: what are the column names which not supports null values?

Comment: they are - AccountNo
AccDate
CurrentAddress

Answer (score 0):

Use IsNULL, If you goal is to insert some default value..

```
INSERT INTO account (sSurname, sName, sIdNo)
SELECT 
         ISNULL(Client.LASTNAME, 0) AS sSurname
        ,ISNULL(Client.FIRSTNAME,0) AS sName
        ,ISNULL(Client.DATEOFBIRTH,0) AS sIdNo
FROM Client
INNER JOIN Account__MEMBER
ON Account__MEMBER.AccountKEY=Client.AccountKEY
ORDER BY Client.LASTNAME;
```

If you want to filter out null's then use a where clause

```
WHERE Client.LASTNAME IS NOT NULL OR COLUMN2 IS NOT NULL...
```

IF you want to update try something like this.

```
UPDATE account
 sSurname= Client.LASTNAME
,sName= Client.FIRSTNAME
,sIdNo= Client.DATEOFBIRTH
FROM Client C
    INNER JOIN Account__MEMBER AM ON AM.AccountKEY=C.AccountKEY
    WHERE -- FILTER COLUMNS THAT ARE NULL 
    --E.G. AM.ID IS NOT NULL OR c.LASTNAME IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: hi   
thanks for replying.
I have values for sSurname, sName , sIdNo. That is not a problem
what I need is how do I, while updating sSurname, sName , sIdNo  values, either skip over the nulls in the other column's or make the other columns '0' ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
INSERT INTO account (sSurname, sName, sIdNo,  AccountNo, AccDate, CurrentAddress)
SELECT Client.LASTNAME, Client.FIRSTNAME, Client.DATEOFBIRTH, 0 AS 'AccountNo',
GetDate() as 'AccDate', 'N/A' as 'CurrentAddress'
FROM Client
INNER JOIN Account__MEMBER
ON Account__MEMBER.AccountKEY=Client.AccountKEY
ORDER BY Client.LASTNAME;
```

**Solution 2:**

> You can add default values whatever you want for these columns in column property in
>   Sql Server Management studio.

Comment: sorry to worry again but I'm getting an
 'Error converting data type varchar to bigint' error ?
its on line 1 .
AccountNo is set as bigint.. anything I can do ?


I don't really want to interfere with the set up on table A..

Comment: what are the datatypes you used for these 3 columns?

Comment: On table A :  
AccountNo - bigint
AccDate - datetime
CurrentAddress - varchar
.   not sure if this is relevant but I have a vb app that the client will use to access the database table A and the app will insert the date and the account number when the client clicks save the first time they access the account. which is why I don't want to change column details on table A

Comment: I guess problem is with the Client.DATEOFBIRTH, because I guess this value should be varchar and column which you are using to insert this value is sIdNo which is I guess bigint.

Comment: hi  problem seems to be accountNo , this is set to bigint.   if I remove the accountNo Part from the query and if I tick allow nulls on table A for column accountNo . The query runs fine and imports everything. Is there anything I can do with out ticking allow null ?